# segue .. from anywhere to the first scene (after applicationDidBecomeActive)

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a storyboard app with say ten scenes.

There are sundry segues such as `PreToFront`, `UserToBombs`, `BombsToPre` and so on.

[image]

My problem:  Say the user exits the app (I mean, presses the iPad home button).

When the user again opens the app, `applicationDidBecomeActive` ...

I want to, no matter what, go to the initial scene.

So again no matter what scene the user is on, I want it to segue to a particular scene, when the app opens.  (Indeed, ideally the initial scene.)

How could this be done?

Comment: Is your initial view controller a `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 3):

Without any details other than 'resetting' to the first view controller on application did become active, the following may do what you need.

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
    UIViewController *firstViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = firstViewController;  
}
```

If your app is is based on a UINavigationController, you can just call `[mainNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]` in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't use segues, but I think it can work if you give an ID to the desired view controller:

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

   [self presentViewControllerAnimated:NO];

 }


- (void)presentViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *destinationViewNavigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"destination"];
    [self presentViewController:destinationViewNavigationController animated:animated completion:nil];     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need more complex logic than **alivingston** says above, you can use **Unwind Segues**.

1) implement this method in view controller you want to go down:

```
- (IBAction)unwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue
```

2) for above view controllers create **named** unwind segues to this **view controller** and this method in **Interface Builder**.

3) in `applicationDidBecomeActive` get top view controller. Like this (*but keep in mind that you should get the presented view controller recursively*):

```
UIViewController* topController = self.window.rootViewController;
if (topController.presentedViewController) topController = topController.presentedViewController;
```

4) call `- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender` on *topController* with specific identifier

Happy coding!